# overloading input stream in c++ what is wrong in my solution

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

```
istream & read_person(istream & in, person * & p){
  char start, end, s, n, t, e = '\0';
  string surname, name, tele, email, pers ="";
  if ((in >> start)&&(start =='<')) {
    if((in >> pers >> s >> surname >> n >> name >> end) && (start == '<' &&     pers == "person" && s == 'S' && n == 'N' && end == '>')) {
   person p_0(name,surname);
   p = &p_0;
}
else if((in >> pers >> s >> surname >> n >> name >> t >> tele >> end) && (start == '<' && pers == "person" && s == 'S' && n == 'N' && t == 'T'  && end == '>')
{
  person_with_telephone p_t(name, surname, tele);
  p = &p_t;
}
 else if((in >> pers >> s >> surname >> n >> name >> e >> email >> end) && (start == '<' && pers == "person" && s == 'S' && n == 'N' && e == 'E'  && end == '>'))
{
  person_with_email p_e(name, surname, email);
  p = &p_e;
}
else if((in >> pers >> s >> surname >> n >> name >> t >> tele >> e >> email >> end) && (start == '<' && pers == "person" && s == 'S' && t== 'T' && e == 'E' && n == 'N' && end == '>'))
{
  person_with_telephone_and_email p_t_e(name, surname, tele, email);
  p = &p_t_e;
    }
   else
     {
       in.setstate(ios::badbit); //read failed

     }
 }
 return in;
}
```

Here is the person class that i have which is quite easy to understand it has name and surname two strings and one print method

```
class person
{
  string name;
  string surname;

  public:

  person(){}

  person(string strName, string strSurname):name(strName),surname(strSurname)  { }        

  void set_name(string strName)
  {    name= strName;  }

   void set_surname(string strSurname)
  {    surname= strSurname;  }

  string get_name()const
  {    return name;  }

  string get_surname()const
  {    return surname;  }

  virtual  bool has_telephone_p()const
  {    return false;  }

  virtual bool has_email_p()const
  {    return false;  }


  virtual void print(ostream& out)const
  {
           out << "<person S "<<get_surname()<<" N " << get_name() << ">";
   }    

    };
```

i am trying to overload iostream that can read as this format

it reads fine for first one but does not read for rest of the cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, don't use pointers for this.

```
person p_0(name,surname); // temporary person
p = &p_0; // assign its address to a pointer
```

`p_0` goes eventually out of scope. You're left with an invalid pointer and undefined behavior.

Change the `operator>>` signature to this:

```
istream &read_person(istream &in, person &p); // no pointer here, just reference
```

and adjust the code inside:

```
p = p_0;                   // making a copy
p = person(name, surname); // you might as well do it in one line
p = {name, surname};       // or like this
```

Don't incline away from idiomatic approaches towards error-prone ones in the future.

Comment: i am very new to C++ what shall i use instead of this

Comment: I removed the pointer from the parameter type, you remove the ampersands after the assignments to `p` in the function body.

Comment: while calling to check this function i am using something like this             person *pp=0 ;
            while (read_person(cin, pp) && pp)
       cout << *pp << endl;

Comment: main problem is that it does not go in else loop i can only read one person < person S first N person > while i go to read second one with telephone it does not give any response i wonder why

Comment: i understand the problem when it goes it else if part its already at somewhere in middle of istream is there any method that i can reset it to start from beginning.

Comment: That's only possible if you re-create the stream. What you can do, is `std::getline` from `in` to `std::string line;` and then create `std::istringstream iss(line);` in each `if` and use that.